# jQuery Minicolors - How to write value in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found here on Stackoverflow similar topics but not the same.
I am using jquery Minicolors on my project: https://github.com/claviska/jquery-miniColors/

Everything work fine, but I need to do easy thing - I need to get actual color value and write it to the HTML document. So for example I need to do this:

```
<p><script>document.write(actualColor);</script></p>
```

Simply just write the actual color code anywhere in static HTML. I am very bad in JS and I didnt find some working solution.

My minicolors code look like this:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('.color-picker-1').each( function() {
                $(this).minicolors({
                    defaultValue: $(this).attr('data-defaultValue') || '',
                    inline: $(this).attr('data-inline') === 'true',
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And I use just this input for picking color:

```
<input type="text" id="inline" class="color-picker-1" data-inline="true" value="#4fc8db">
```

What can I do? I guess solution is very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On change of the color, re-assign the value to the input element so that it contains new value. Then you can use that value. If you want, you can create another hidden input element to store the color values as well.

'change' event gets triggered when color value is changed. This is where all DOM manipulation should go into.

```
$("#inline").minicolors({
    change: function(hex, opacity) {
        $("#inline").val(hex);
    }
});
```

On your code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('.color-picker-1').each( function() {
                $(this).minicolors({
                    defaultValue: $(this).attr('data-defaultValue') || '',
                    inline: $(this).attr('data-inline') === 'true',
                    change: function(hex, opacity) {
                        $(this).val(hex);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: So, my actual code (without minicolors library - just for see) Where is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzqgpmz0/

Comment: Thanks, I have only problem with writing the value now. Why just <script>document.write(hex);</script> didnt work?

Comment: It didn't work, because 'hex' by itself cannot write its value on change. You need some DOM element and event to print it in. It can't self execute.

Comment: If it answered your question then please accept the answer by clicking the tick. Thank you.

Comment: OK thanks a lot, can you help with this? Its difficult to edit my code within using a DOM element? I am looking for some solution for minicolors but without success.

Comment: Where do you want to get the value?

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzqgpmz0/3/ - This way you can keep a 'p' tag and you don't need to assign id to it

Comment: Basically anywehere in the same HTML file document. So for example in <p> tag. Just write the hex code. Nothing more, nothing less. :-)

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzqgpmz0/6/ and let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you, I rewrite this a little bit, but I still dint know how write the color. Lets look here please: http://jsfiddle.net/okqe4ea4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/okqe4ea4/1/ You need to have the input value before the p tag

Comment: OK, I got it but how can I write the HEX code inside <p class="color"></p>? Because my code doesnt work.

Comment: For that you need to check if you are getting any errors in console or not. Maybe the syntax you are writing is wrong, or maybe there are javascript errors on other section of your page. Without knowing the error its difficult to tell the solution. .html(hex) should populate hex code inside the selector element.